# How to implement a queue of worker threads processing URLs

Tags: python, multithreading

I am a new to python and having some issues with threading and queues.

Basically i have a file of URL's, and would like to create a queue of 10 workers which sequentially work down through the file and perform a urllib2 request.

I just cant get my head around it! Could anyone help please with some simple links or code?

Thanks, Matt

Comment: i think you need to show first what you already have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built in "Queue" module would make a good underlying queue for your app.  It handles all multi-threaded locking semantics for you.

http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html

You can load your file, populate your Queue, spin up your worker threads, and have them pull from the Queue and do their work.

Comment: I used this link and example to help build out what i wanted in the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This python threadpool module is very helpful for what you describe. The author has a few examples for how to use it on the main page and in the docs.

http://www.chrisarndt.de/projects/threadpool/